# Updating ListView in Android with button

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm starting programming for Android so I don't have much idea.
I have a .xml with a button and a listview and when I click the button I get into the onClick method that I told it and I want my listView to update, but I'm not able to make this happen :S

I leave you my java code:

For the list:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

String[] values = new String[] {};

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For the button:

```
public void onClickMyButton() {

            values = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

If you need anymore code, I'll copy it with no problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your items in the adapter before you notify the adapter the data has changed:

```
    public void onClickMyButton(View view) {
            values = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
            if(adapter!=null){
                        adapter.clear()
                        for(String value:values)
                                    adapter.add(value)
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Well, I've tried that and that isn´t working. When I try the app it crashes when I click the button. The button and list are both in the same xml activity, but I don't think that is a problem :S

Comment: `03-24 20:05:10.853: E/AndroidRuntime(605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 20:05:10.853: E/AndroidRuntime(605): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClickMyButton(View) in the activity class com.example.buttonlist.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'`

Comment: Still have a lot of errors, I tried to post you here the entire logcat errors but it wont let me :S Here are some of them: `E/AndroidRuntime(749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main; E/AndroidRuntime(749): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity; E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591); E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084); E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966); E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)`

Comment: I need to see all log from your error to understand the problem, in your last message you have posted the beginning of the error but not the real cause of it :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after trying a lot of possibilities, this one the only one that worked as I wanted, maybe not the best one:

```
public void onClickMyButton(View view) {
    values = new String[] {"1","2","3"} ;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```